# How do you send an XMLHttpRequest to GAE with user info?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, xmlhttprequest

How do you send an XMLHttpRequest to Google App Engine that identifies the logged in user?

My site uses the built-in login system to get to the page, like this:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    u := user.Current(c)
    if u == nil {
        url, err := user.LoginURL(c, r.URL.String())
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        w.Header().Set("Location", url)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %v!", u)
}
```

How do I include that user info when doing an XMLHttpRequest from that page to a different url handled by the same GAE app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HttpOnly cookie used to identify the user is automatically included in the XMLHttpRequest if the user is logged in.  You can then get the user as normal:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    u := user.Current(c)
```